# A closed expression for $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kA)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, recreational-mathematics

How do I find a closed expression for $$\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kA)$$ any idea about how to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that your expression is the real part of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\exp(ikA)$, which can be evaluated in closed form as it is the partial sum of a geometric series.